# Different tags in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm just getting started with Ruby and Ruby on Rails, so excuse me if this is a simple question. I've noticed that in some ERB files, there is a difference to using `<%= %>` and `<% %>`, but what is the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is as follows:-
<%= %> would execute and print the value of rails code written inside and <% %> would just execute the rails code.

Thanks, Anubhaw

Comment: You can also do <%= -%>.  The minus at the end removes the newline.  Useful for formatting the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= %>` in ERB equals to `<?php echo ?>` in PHP.

Comment: Or `<?= ?>` in PHP if short tags are enabled on your server